# Error while passing bash user input to sql statement

Tags: linux, oracle, bash, sqlplus

I am trying to write a bash function which prompts for the schema owner and drops all the corresponding schemas.

```
function db_cleanup

{
        #accept user input
        read -p "Schema Owner: " input

        sqlplus -s $usr1/$pwd1@$sid1 << EOF


declare
        usr_d varchar2(10) := '&input'; --reas user input here
        sqlstmt varchar2(128);
begin   
        sqlstmt := 'drop user '||$usr_d||' cascade';
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlstmt); execute immediate sqlstmt;

        sqlstmt := 'drop user ab_'||$usr_d||' cascade';
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlstmt); execute immediate sqlstmt;

        sqlstmt := 'drop user xy_'||$usr_d||' cascade';
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlstmt); execute immediate sqlstmt;
end;
/
EOF
}
```

Output looks like:

```
    Enter Schema Owner: ABC
    Enter value for usr_in: 
    User requested Interrupt or EOF detected.

-bash-3.2$
```

Please let me know how to fix this one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't you finish with `> EOF`?

Comment: Think it should be `'$input'` instead of `'&input'` in the line right below `declare`. And perhaps `\$usr_d` instead of `$usr_d`

Comment: @244an: Replacing `$input` with `&input` fixed one problem i.e., I am not seeing `Enter value for usr_in: ` anymore. But the later one is still having problem - `sqlstmt := 'drop user '||||' cascade';
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "|" when expecting one of the following:
( - + case mod new null <an identifier>
`

Comment: `usr_d` is declared in the PL/SQL `declare` block, not in the shell; so it should not be prefixed with `$` when you use it in the concatenation. But why not just use `$input` - not sure what `usr_d` is adding?

Comment: That make sense since he is using `sqlstmt` w/o prefix. I don't know about sql syntax, I thought OP knows :) Is `||` the correct way to concatenate strings?

Comment: @AlexPoole Using `$input` works fine but I wanted to know how to call the variable which is defined in the `declare block` in the sql statement.

Anyways thank you!

Comment: @244an I think so...because I am able to concatenate if I use `$input` in the sql statement.

Comment: Yes, `||` will concatenate in Oracle SQL, but it needs to be `... ' ||usr_d||' cascade';` - without the `$`. @244an, do you want to consolidate all that in a proper answer?

Comment: @Alex Poole: I think you contributed the most to the answer, so you should do it.

Comment: @AlexPoole It is working the way you suggested without `$`. My script is working as expected. But it is printing `Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP and Data Mining options
SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP and Data Mining options` on screen which I want to hide. I am already using `set timing off, set serveroutput on size 10000, set feedback off, spool $log_file.out`. After this fix my script will be completed.

Comment: The `-s` flag to SQL*Plus should stop the banners being displayed; have you lost that?

Comment: @AlexPoole   Yes...I missed it. I think while re-writing I missed on the flag. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Pulling together comments from @244an and myself:

- `'&input'` should be `'$input'`, because you're referring to a shell variable.
- `$usr_d` should be `usr_d` (without the `$`) because you are *not* referring to a sheel variable here; this is coming from the PL/SQL `declare` section.
- the `-s` flag to SQL*Plus suppresses the banners; but you original question showed that so not sure if you've lost that somewhere along the way.

So:

```
function db_cleanup
{
        #accept user input
        read -p "Schema Owner: " input

        sqlplus -s $usr1/$pwd1@$sid1 << EOF
set timing off
set feedback off
set serverputput on size 10000
spool $log_file.out

declare
        usr_d varchar2(10) := '$input';
        sqlstmt varchar2(128);
begin   
        sqlstmt := 'drop user '||usr_d||' cascade';
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlstmt);
        execute immediate sqlstmt;

        sqlstmt := 'drop user ab_'||usr_d||' cascade';
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlstmt);
        execute immediate sqlstmt;

        sqlstmt := 'drop user xy_'||usr_d||' cascade';
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlstmt);
        execute immediate sqlstmt;
end;
/
EOF
}
```

Not sure if you might want to sanitize the schema you're given... there are a number of users you really don't want to drop by accident. [Any of these](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10575/tdpsg_user_accounts.htm#BABGEGFI) for a start, and you might have your own too.